# DMCA Notice received from Microsoft's Azure server will effect in Google ranking?

Tags: google-search-console, google-ranking, microsoft, dmca

I am doing a research on a case.

A company received DMCA notice through Microsoft Azure Platform and after some days their ranking went down, their few pages were unindexed by Google Webmaster.

So is there any correlation between these two events?

I understand that Google penalizes on Plagiarism and the heaviest penalty is unindexing (unlisting) those pages.But is the same applies in this case?

Comment: DMCA complaints are listed in searchable databases, such as [Lumen](https://lumendatabase.org/) and [Copyscape](https://www.copyscape.com/dmca-takedown-notice-search/). It may also be listed in their Google Search Console, or [Google's Transparency Report](https://transparencyreport.google.com/copyright/explore). If DMCA complaints for the site can be found in those, it's [very possible that Google will penalize it](https://www.shoutmeloud.com/dmca-takedown-penalty-added-as-new-factor-in-google-ranking.html), regardless if the complaint was initially made through Microsoft's Azure Platform.

Comment: Hi @dan Thanks for the reply. I checked and it s not visible on Lumen and Copyscape, so there might be some other reasons.

Comment: No problem. You should also check Google's Transparency Report and Google Search Console. If it received a DMCA, more than likely it has duplicate content too, so Google may just remove URLs based on that as well.

Comment: Hi.. thanks. The Google's Transparency Report is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

On occasion entities that file a DMCA take down notice against a web host will also do so against search engines to try and get rid of as many traces of the offending content as possible. This has the net effect of reducing or eliminating ranking as the various major signals used in ranking are lost due to removal of the page or site from the index.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks. This would be also helpful. I want to make further research on this. Could you share me any related resources?

Comment: An easy way is to check https://lumendatabase.org, Google for a long time has been uploading DMCA notices they receive there. I can't cite a specific reference at this point as it has been a little while since I have read the resources that outlined this and none as I recall specifically made reference to ranking, but given that Google removes pages from the index based on lawful DMCA notices and that the ranking is near real time based on the inverted index it is a fair supposition.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Noted. I will keep a close look to the lumendatabse